# Can inequalities be proven by taking all variables to be equal?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, functional-inequalities

For example-
$$ \frac{a}{c+a-b} + \frac{b}{a+b-c} + \frac{c}{b+c-a} \geq 3. $$
This can be proven if take a=b=c
Is there any theorem regarding this?

Comment: Think about "${a\over b}\le 2$" ...

Comment: $(a-b)^2\le 3$ is true for $a=b$, but that does not prove the (false) statement that it is true for all $a,b$

Comment: It is true that in many classical and competition-type inequalities equality holds when all variables are equal. It is helpful to know when equality holds- it can be used as a hint for how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: This might be part of a proof. You may be able to show, for example, that a function (typically one that’s invariant under a permutation of its variables) attains a global minimum (or maximum) for a given sum of the variables when the variables are equal. Here’s a somewhat-related example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695727/inequality-involving-four-numbers/1696223#1696223

Comment: Are the $a,b,c$ assumed to be sides of a triangle?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No they are assumed to be positive reals.